# Break down and speed up Rake task

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rake

Our application has a feature that requires a rake tast to run every day at a specific time **over all the users**. This involves computation of some of their attributes and running through db queries and sending a push notification to every user. As such, the task has been designed to run in O(n) but that would still mean growing total time to finish with increasing user base. And we want the task to finish in not more than a minute - it already is take 8 minutes at 14000 users and also ever increasing the CPU util (throughout the rest of the day, the average cpu util sits around 10% but goes up to 50% when the task runs). I want to solve two problems here - make the task run in lesser time and bring down the cpu util the task run spikes.

Tech Specs - Sinatra application serving an API for the app, running on Phusion Passenger (nginx module), using MongoDB and deployed on a c3.large ec2 instance.

P.S - I don't have much knowledge about how parallel processing and threading are done in Ruby and if it can solve this issue, but can bucketing the total users and paralelly computing those buckets be an answer? If so, how do I go about doing something like that? I want to avoid buying out a bigger server just for this purpose as rest of the time it handles the requests quite easily like I pointed out above.

Comment: You need a background worker. Then you can break your users in batches of, say, 1000 and schedule those batches for processing. This way you can tune the total processing time by changing number of workers. More workers - more resources used, but less overall time. You'll likely also need several machines for the workers (to spread the load). A good background job solution is sidekiq. Others include resque, delayed_job.

Comment: Thank you @SergioTulentsev,  for your input. I do use Sidekiq in our solution to deliver notifications such as new message but not sure if Sidekiq is solid enough to handle large tasks like the one mentioned. If I were to go the Sidekiq way, what best practices would you suggest to make sure the tasks run successfully or auto-restart in case of failure? Its extremely imporant for these batched tasks to finish. I'm gonna Google on these issues, but would appreciate your insight on the same.

Comment: Sidekiq is production-ready. And it even has auto-restart out-of-the-box, IIRC. So you should be all set.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I've yet to try Sidekiq out, but I tried out to include the computing tasks per bucket between a `fork do end` block. What I noticed was, while the task ran significantly faster, it also maxed out my cpu. Is forking like this a bad practice or what can be changed to run fork without eating too much CPU? 

I'll soon update this thread with what Sidekiq does for me.

Comment: If you spread cpu-intensive work to multiple cpu, the job will complete faster, because more CPUs will be at it. Not sure what surprises you here.